# Fail to change the backgound-color of 'option' inside html 'select' tag

Tags: html, css

I have a `select` html tag, and I want the `background-color` of the `option` to be alternated between rows, and below is my try

```
<select name="j_idt8:j_idt13" size="1">    
   <option value="value1" class="option1">label1</option>
   <option value="value2" class="option2">label2</option>
   <option value="value3" class="option1">label3</option>
   <option value="value4" class="option2">label4</option>
   <option value="value5" class="option1">label5</option>
</select>

option.option1 {
   background-color: #ccc;
}

option.option2 {
   background-color: #fcc;
}
```

This only work on FF but not working on Chrome and safari, can a CSS guru help me figure this out? I attach the jsfiddle as well so you can just open them between different browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/cYEE2/

**Note**: 
Chrome: 20.0.1132.47
Safari: 5.1.7
Firefox: 13.0.1

Comment: It works fine for me on Chromium 18 (Linux), however browser support varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being able to use CSS to change formatting of individual OPTION elements in a SELECT element is, unfortunately, browser-specific. Your CSS above won't work on some browsers.

There are CSS-friendly alternatives to the SELECT element that you can use, e.g. jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Coloring select options is not supported in all browsers and even where it is there are usually problems with paddings etc.

My advice is to simply use it in browsers which support it (Firefox fully, Chrome partially but ignores paddings and Safari fully) and forget about it in those which don't.

Other browsers simply do not support this option.